# Spherical integral

Tags: special-functions, vector-analysis

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be fixed.
Is there a nice expression for the following integral taken over the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
$$
\int_{\|x\|=1} e^{2\pi i (x \cdot y)}~dx
$$

Comment: The integral is zero (since the set $\{ x | \|x\| = 1 \}$ has measure zero), so I suppose that is a nice expression.

Comment: Clearly $dx$ is the surface area element and not Lebesgue measure.

Comment: The integral is being taken with respect to surface measure on the unit sphere.

Comment: It isn't that nice. Parametrize the hypersphere $S^{n-1}$ by hyper-spherical polar coordinates:
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 &= \cos\theta_1,\\
x_2 &= \sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2,\\
&\;\vdots\\
\end{align}
$$
The area element $d\Omega_{n-1}$ for $S^{n-1}$ will proportional to $(\sin\theta_1)^{n-2} d\theta_1$. You will find
$$
\int_{S^{n-1}} e^{i\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}} d\Omega_{n-1}
\propto
\int_0^\pi e^{i y\cos\theta} (\sin\theta)^{n-1} d\theta
$$
which equals to a bunch of [Bessel function of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind_:_J.CE.B1).

Comment: @achillehui It isn't that nice, but it is the best one so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, consider the $n=3$ case to have a point of reference. Since we integrate over all directions on the sphere, we may take $\vec{y}$ to define the vertical axis i.e. $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}=y \cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the azimuthal angle. Then the integral in spherical coordinates (normalized by the surface area) is

\begin{align}\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\exp({2\pi i\, \vec{x}\cdot \vec{y}})\,d^2x
&=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\!\!\int_0^{2\pi}\exp({2\pi i\, y \, \cos\theta})\sin\theta\,d\phi\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[-\frac{\exp({2\pi i y \cos\theta})}{2\pi i y}\right]_0^\pi\\
&=\frac{1}{4\pi iy}\left(e^{2\pi i y}-e^{-2\pi i y}\right)=\frac{\sin(2\pi y)}{2\pi y}
\end{align}

Note that this goes to $1$ as $y\to 0$ as it should. (A reader versed in special functions will recognize this as the zeroth spherical Bessel function $j_0(2\pi y)$.)

We now want to generalize to arbitrary $n\geq 2$ i.e. the integral $$I_n(y):=\frac{1}{S_{n-1}}\int_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\exp{(2\pi i\,\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y})}\,d^{n-1}x.$$ Note that $I_n$ can only be a function of $y$ alone; also, this integral is normalized as $I_n(y=0)=1$. We can show that $I_n(y)$ satisfies a differential equation by taking the Laplacian of both sides:

\begin{align}
\nabla^2 I_n(y)
&=\frac{1}{y^{n-1}}\frac{d}{dy}\left( y^{n-1}\frac{d I_n}{dy}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_k^2}\left[\frac{1}{S_{n-1}}\int_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\exp{(2\pi i\,\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y})}\,d^{n-1}x\right]\\
&=\frac{(2\pi i)^2}{S_{n-1}}\int_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_k^2\right)\exp{(2\pi i\,\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y})}\,d^{n-1}x\\
&=\frac{(2\pi i)^2}{S_{n-1}}\int_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\exp{(2\pi i\,\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y})}\,d^{n-1}x &\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_k^2\right)=\Vert x \Vert^2=1\right)\\
&=-(2\pi)^2 I_n(y)
\end{align}

To simplify the LHS we have recalled the form of the [Laplacian in hyperspherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#N_dimensions) for the case of spherically symmetric potentials. So all that remains is to solve the linear second-order ODE above, which can be simplified to
$$I_n''(y)+\left(\frac{n-1}{y}\right)I_n'(y)+(2\pi)^2 I_n(y)=0$$ This can be placed into the standard form of Bessel's equation by a suitable transformation. Rather than carry this out by hand, I'll just cite [WolframAlpha](http://po.st/M5fPXR):

$$I_n(y)=c_1 y^{1-n/2} J_{\frac{n}{2}-1}(2\pi y)+c_2 y^{1-n/2} Y_{\frac{n}{2}-1}(2\pi y)$$ where $J_n$ and $Y_n$ are $n$-th Bessel functions of the first and second kind respectively. We can ignore the second solution since it diverges at $y=0$; by comparison, the first solution may be checked to behave as $\pi^{n/2-1}/\Gamma(n/2) $ as $y\to 0$. Since  $I_n(0)=1$ we conclude that $$I_n(y)=\frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{(\pi y)^{n/2-1}}J_{\frac{n}{2}-1}(2\pi y).$$ As a check, note that for $n=3$ we [recover](http://po.st/iFEmCv) the same answer of $\dfrac{\sin 2\pi y}{2\pi y}$ as obtained earlier. (The case of odd $n$ gives Bessel functions of half-integer order i.e. spherical Bessel functions which can always be expressed through trig. functions.)

Since the $(n-1)$-dimensional surface area is $S_{n-1}=\pi^{n/2}/\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)$, we conclude that

> $$\int_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\exp{(2\pi i\,\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y})}\,d^{n-1}x = 
> \frac{n \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)} \frac{\Gamma(\frac n2)}{(\pi y)^{n/2-1}}J_{\frac{n}{2}-1}(2\pi y)=2\pi\,y^{1-n/2} J_{\frac{n}{2}-1}(2\pi y).$$

Comment: This is a very nice approach!